# Using Sprintf With Arguments Just Like İn Vprintf

Tags: c, printf

I try to achieve same thing in vprintf function using sprintf to write into buffer, however I can not do it. What is my mistake?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>


char latestPrint[1000];
int currentPositionPrint=0;



void WriteFrmtd(char *format, ...) {
   va_list args;
   
   va_start(args, format);
   vprintf(format, args);
   va_end(args);
}

void WriteToPrint(char *format, ...) {
   va_list args;
   
   va_start(args, format);
   currentPositionPrint+=sprintf(currentPositionPrint+latestPrint , format, args);
   va_end(args);
   
}

int main () {
   WriteFrmtd("%d variable argument\n", 1);
   WriteFrmtd("%d variable %s\n", 2, "argumentsqweqweqweqwe");
   
   WriteToPrint("%d variable %s\n", 2, "argumentsqweqweqweqwe");
   
   printf("%s",latestPrint);
   return(0);
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 variable argument
2 variable argumentsqweqweqweqwe
1698242904 variable 1698242904 variable
```

Comment: All [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) variants have corresponding [`vprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf) functions.

Comment: Thx for the info

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? The answer is pretty obvious, but the question is well asked, well formatted and it contains a [mcve] etc...

Comment: Who knows, everyone has a reason to dislike nowadays, don't they? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `vsprintf` (same as `vprintf` but using an array as output instead of `stdout`):

```
void WriteToPrint(char *format, ...)
{
   va_list args;
   
   va_start(args, format);
   currentPositionPrint += vsprintf(latestPrint + currentPositionPrint, format, args);
   va_end(args);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `sprintf` with variable arguments. You need to use `vsprintf` instead:

Change:

```
currentPositionPrint += sprintf(currentPositionPrint+latestPrint , format, args);
```

to:

```
currentPositionPrint += vsprintf(currentPositionPrint+latestPrint , format, args);
```

**Free hint:** use spaces between operators: `foo += bar` is more readable than `foo+=bar`.